# how can return two string from a method separately without appending?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, methods, out-parameters

I have method that will receive a string input(with message & mode name) and the method will separate the string input in to two strings(1.message 2.mode name) according to separator.
but i need to return this separated two string at a time.please provide me a good way to do this.can i use "out" and return in one method? if yes, please tell me any links to do the out parameter.
(or) any good way if you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use out parameters:

```
string myMethod(string input, out secondOutput)
{
   secondOutput="bla";
   return "xyz";
}
```

you can also use 2 out parameters:

```
void myMethod(string input, out firstOutput, out secondOutput)
{
   firstOutput="bla";
   secondOutput = "xyz";
}
```

Or like others suggested and I think is preferrable most of the time, using an array:

```
string[] myMethod(string input)
{
   return new string[] {firstOutput, secondOutput);
}
```

If you can tell us what the method is for we might help you choosing the best alternative.

Comment: yes this answer i need...but problem with receiver side..how can i assign this values to separate strings

Comment: in the case of two out parameters how can i assign?i am calling the method message = [self myMethod]; my method return two put parameters.the how can i set it to

Comment: hi, i wrote a method with out pram

-(NSString *)messageDecryption:(NSString *)receivedMessage outParam:(out)messageCondent {
messageCondent = [receivedMessage substringFromIndex:2]; return [receivedMessage substringToIndex:1];

}

then i passed the parameters

NSString *messageCondent; NSString *mode = [myclassobject messageDecryption:message outParam:messageCondent];

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your 2 string in a Array and return that Array ?

Comment: can i use return key word to  return a string (message) and out parameter string as mode name.

Comment: any problms..is it better than declaring a array?